# jQuery $.ajax stripping out JSON object properties in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, safari

I am using the following code:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: "http://www.earthquakescanada.nrcan.gc.ca/api/earthquakes/latest/7d.json",
    dataType: 'json',       
    success: successHandler
} );

var successHandler = function ( data ) {
    console.log( data );
}
```

For some reason and only in Safari, the "location" property for the objects returned are stripped out. Can anyone explain why and suggest a solution?

Comment: Problem is the source, not the script - try something server side (e.g curl to grep data?) and report this truly weird bug to the service too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a **jQuery** or **$.ajax** problem, but the json resource you are trying to get, has a kind of **user agent** controller.

Try to open the url in Chrome and then in Safari, you will see two different json files from the same url  http://www.earthquakescanada.nrcan.gc.ca/api/earthquakes/latest/7d.json

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using `$.getJSON(...)` instead of `$.ajax(...)`, since that will get you the parsed json object in your `data` variable